# Can Django REST Framework indicate readonly fields to client?

Tags: django-rest-framework

This is a newbie question. I see that the browsable API for Django rest framework is able to detect readonly fields defined in my serializer and exclude them from the HTML form that is presented to the user for PUT/POST operations.

What is the mechanism used here and can I use the same to indicate readonly fields to the remote client? I don't see any difference in the format between readonly fields and writable fields in the JSON object itself, so I'm guessing that there is some metadata involved but I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

I'm using Django version 1.7 and django-rest-framework version 3.1.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should send an OPTION request to Django REST framework to get an insight of the expected content - see the option button on the browsable interface.

See the id field under the following sample:

```
{
    "name": "Task List",
    "description": "",
    "renders": [
        "application/json",
        "text/html"
    ],
    "parses": [
        "application/json",
        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "multipart/form-data"
    ],
    "actions": {
        "POST": {
            "id": {
                "type": "integer",
                "required": false,
                "read_only": true,
                "label": "ID"
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "required": true,
                "read_only": false,
                "label": "Name",
                "max_length": 64
            },
            "owner": {
                "type": "field",
                "required": true,
                "read_only": false,
                "label": "Owner",
                "choices": [
                    {
                        "display_name": "admin",
                        "value": "admin"
                    },
                    {
                        "display_name": "cody",
                        "value": "cody"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

U should use [django-swagger](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger), it is an app to document django rest framework APIs.

In you serializer field, you can set a help text, you can use it to mark as read only field the your client should read that on APIs document.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. Since I'm still relatively new to this, I'll go with the OPTIONS approach suggested by Linovia for now.